# Cannot get GCM configuration file

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am integrating GCM in one of my project. For this we need to get the configuration file. I am referring [this GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) link.

When I click on "GET CONFIGURATION FILE" then it is redirected to a page. However, I can't see anything on that page. It keeps loading and nothing is displayed.

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: first time your doing it from your gmail account

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps for getting configuration if your **first time login to google developer account**.

```
1. open google developer console.
2. login to developer console.
3. create project with valid name.
4. then goto the API section & enable GCM API. 
5. Then get the configuration file.
```

Comment: I already had GCM enabled for an old test project. I had to disable and re-enable it before the url for creating a configuration file would load properly.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to setup a project first by opening google developer console. At top right there is option of create project and if you have already created one then it would show the name of already created project. After creating project select it and Enable the api for `Google Cloud Messaging for Android`. Then go to [this link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) and get your configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

Don't open configuration page like this way. Try to open same page from your developer console. May be this way you are able to open page.