# Generate google-services.json for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

This might be a stupid question but I am facing an issue when trying to generate my `google-services.json` file for my app. I am following this [guide from the google developers team](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start) to setup my project for analytics but when I click on the [get configuration file](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=analytics&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fdevguides%2Fcollection%2Fandroid%2Fv4%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Analytics) button nothing happens, I just get a loading spinner that never ends.

I tried on different browsers, it's still the same. I checked the chrome console and got :

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passiv…3Dtrue%26cntlbl%3DContinue%2BAdding%2BAnalytics%26cntapi%3Danalytics&hl=en' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://console.developers.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I am having the same problem! Relieved to know that I am not alone ... BTW, is this a temporary problem or what? Apart from trying three different browsers I tried using two google accounts, but no luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well well, got a workaround. You console log helped: I clicked on the URL in the log ("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passiv…3Dtrue%26cntlbl%3DContinue%2BAdding%2BAnalytics%26cntapi%3Danalytics&hl=en") and it led me to the right page and I have been able to generate a `google-services.json` for my app.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that by myself, thanks, it seems to be working!

Answer (score 8):

You are trying this link while configuration https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start

So please do the following steps 
[image]

Click on the **GET A CONFIGURATION FILE**

Now Choose your App Name.
[image]

Click **Configuration Services**
After that the 3rd Window will be open

[image]

Now Choose your Analytics account of your Apps.

Hurry you have done.

Please use all the process and done as it is you can do it.

Let me know if still you have any problem.

Comment: This does not help me as you didn't understand my problem. This answer got the bounty attributed automatically as I was away for the holiday period.

Comment: @alxcms As far I can check your question you have problem to get or generate the Analytics JSON file. So the above answer is for the same which help to generate json file. but if its not your answer can you briefly describe about your problem then may be I can help you. ?

Comment: As stated in my post, when I click on the button "Get a configuration file", this opens a new page with a spinner that never stops. There is an error from google when loading the iframe which contains the configurator. As @Soumya suggested, accessing the iframe link directly in a new tab overpass the issue I encountered. I found another post with the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328113/cannot-get-gcm-configuration-file this might help you understand the problem. Thanks anyway for your answer

Answer (score 1):

A guy from Google analytics team suggests [the solution here](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=835).

Answer (score 0):

Try going through this website to get your configuration file - its the one for Cloud Messaging but it has a button that says "GET CONFIGURATION FILE":

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Also I did experience the same problem last week sometime when configurating cloud messaging myself but it seemed to have resolved itself in the afternoon so it could just be a one day error thing.

Answer (score -1):

**Steps for getting configuration if your first time login to google developer account.**

1. open google developer console.
2. login to developer console.
3. create project with valid name.
4. then goto the API section & enable GCM API.
5. Then get the configuration file.

Comment: Step 5 needs some explanation.  There doesn't appear to be a way to do this after step 4.