# Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have followed this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) to integrate ads in my app. But it shows this error:

[image: error image]

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"





defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.personal.numbermania"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    debug
            {
                debuggable true
            }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'

}

}
```

ads are not showing up in real device.please help me
This is my error after i updated classpath 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY6JO.png)

Comment: Simply you need to generate `google services json` file from console developers `google` and put it inside `app` directory.

Comment: Check this and follow steps given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401143/generate-google-services-json-for-android

Comment: where is google services found?

Comment: Click the link given in answer select your project and get configuration file it will ask you to download file.

Comment: Any of the Answer Didn't work. But reset Android Studios solved Check this to reset:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio

Comment: First, add Firebase to your app, you'll get detailed steps on what to do including downloading the required JSON and putting it in your app root folder. Then try this, that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 260):

Had the same problem.

Fixed by adding the dependency

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

to the **root** `build.gradle`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

Comment: The documents also stress the importance of adding the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at he bottom of the file by writing it in italic.  

 "In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), add a line to the _bottom of the file_."

Comment: sir i got error after add above in build.gradle:                                                                    > Could not find method lasspath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0]

Comment: I'm also getting the `lasspath` error and all I can find on the internet are Kapil Soni's messages that are all left without an answer. So now there's the two of us, sir, you're not alone!

Comment: I guess it won't be useful to anybody but Kapil and me, but to fix the `lasspath` issue just run `grep -R 'lasspath' * | grep -i --invert-match 'classpath'` and you should find the file and line that's causing an issue (basically, a typo).

Comment: Version: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5
Newest Version number here:
'https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: it shows these depricated warnings 
```registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)```

Comment: What really helped me was this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/troubleshooting-faq?hl=de#add-plugins-using-buildscript-syntax

Answer (score 84):

Setting up Gradle `plugins` in the root `build.gradle` meanwhile works alike this:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false
    id "com.android.library" version "7.3.1" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.14" apply false
}
```

Then they can be applied in a module:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}
```

---

Unless some Gradle plugin may depend on it, one can remove/skip the `buildscript` block altogether, but it's still good for defining project-wide version numbers in `buildscript.ext`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '7.3.1'
        gms_version = '4.3.14'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "$agp_version" apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version "$agp_version" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "$gms_version" apply false
}
```

Comment: i was stucked at android studio chipmunk as its new..thanks for the accurate answer

Comment: Bonus marks for doing it the more "modern" way, just using plugins block in root build.gradle file, and not doing buildscript classpath.

Answer (score 67):

Add  `classpath com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`  dependencies at project level build.gradle

Refer the sample block from project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: i had error because i used double quote "" instead of single ''

Answer (score 33):

You can find the correct dependencies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39879418/3996257) apply changes to *app.gradle* and *project.gradle* and tell me about this, greetings!

---

Your *apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'* in *app.gradle* looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.personal.numbermania"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //Here stablished how many cores you want to use your android studi 4g = 4 cores
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug
                {
                    debuggable true
                }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

Add classpath to the **project's gradle**:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

---

Google play services library on SDK Manager:

[image]

Comment: ads are not showing up in real device.I followed below link to integrate ads https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: All components of firebase (ads included) needs this dependencie: *compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'* following this tutorial(https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to install firebase sdk on android. Add, build it and tell me about this, greetings!

Comment: still ads are not seen in real device

Comment: You add this *classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'* in *project.gradle*?

Comment: Following this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start, you need this classpath or your ads not working...

Comment: this is my app gradle code codepaste.net/gf2qe3.Is it correct?

Comment: Show me your *app.gradle* and your *project.gradle*, the last url doesn't work!

Comment: I can opened now... But this is the same image that before images... Your *app.gradle* it's correct I need to see your *project.gradle*!

Comment: The problem is here *classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'*, to use ads in firebase you need to change your classpath to  *classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'* and finally your gradle is correct!

Comment: Then it's other question, show us your error and update your post! Thanks!

Comment: i have updated my question click link of an image named error

Comment: Click in *Help* button from Android Studio and then click on *Check for updates*, open your SDK and install correct library from google services, tell me about this!

Comment: And revision from library?

Comment: which library? there are three libraries  Google play billing library,Google play licensing library,Google play apk  expansion library

Comment: i have installed google play services.only above 3 libraries are present.There is no google play services library

Comment: See photo in my updated answer, above check you can see *Google play services* library, what is your rev version?

Comment: I have installed latest version 36

Comment: Above check *Google repository* I asked from *Google play services* it's impossible that you have version 36 when max is 33, I think you talk about  *Google repository*... Say image the other library you can see is *Google play services*

Comment: I have installed that 33 version

Comment: I can see the problem I think... The problem is in your apply pluguin *apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'*... Your is inside on Android {}... Just put outside this... See my updated answer!

Comment: i have changed my code as u have suggested here is the app build gradle code http://codepaste.net/s9m257.   Is this correct? it is showing an error

Comment: Now is correct, clean and rebuild, then show me your error it's the same?

Comment: Add *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'* in your dependencies... I said at start of post! ;(

Comment: Show me your final *app.gradle* plz

Comment: even if add apply plugin at the bottom still showing error

Comment: Copy my *app.gradle* from my answer! And say me ;)

Comment: You add your *google-services.json* file in your project?

Comment: Then here is the problem... xD 
To connect Firebase project with android you need to generate a *google-services.json* file and add on your project... How? It's easy... Go to Firebase console inside project configuration, inside android applications then select your packcagename and press the button *download google-services.json*, then add this one in app folder. Rebuild and say me it's work!

Comment: sorry there was internet connection problem

Comment: I have added google-services json file in my app folder

Comment: Now, you has correct libraries... This problem is other, I think it's with liked fire base with your app...

Comment: When you create a *new app* on firebase, you add your package name correctly? How to know it? Open your *manifest.xml* and open too your *google-services.json* in client area search *package_name*, the both are equal?

Comment: this is the error            Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Add in your *app.gradle* in *defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled true }*. If you solve this error please close your post, thanks!

Comment: I have followed link .i have added code in dependencies and android manifest file.Should i delete them?

Comment: You can see your *app.gradle* update in my answer ;)

Comment: This package name is equal to firebase package name? :O
Or now it works?

Comment: This package name is equal to firebase package name?

Comment: I have changed package name in google services json file downloaded from firebase console

Comment: The xml that contains your adview, has this line on XML: *xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"* ?

Comment: I think the problem is with google services json file package name and firebase console package name.any idea how to solve it?

Comment: my package name is com.example.personal.numbermania but i have added com.NumberMania.android  in firebase console.so i have changed package name maually after i downloaded google-services json file

Comment: The problem can be there... If you want to do all correctly, my advice is delete actual android app in firebase and create the new one with correctly package name...

Comment: Before do nothing, you change all name packages inside json file? :O

Comment: i have changed my package name to the package name in android manifest xml

Comment: But when i link to firebase it is in the form of com.packagename.android

Comment: This one *com.packagename.android* is a suggestion from firebase... Your package name is good!

Comment: My *google-services.json* in oauth_client has too: "android_info": {
            "package_name": "yourPackage",
            "certificate_hash": "yourHash"
          }

Add this one ;)

Comment: can u edit and send me google services json .my package name is numbermania

Comment: Just add this one inside oauth_client part! ;)

Comment: what is yourpackage? what is certificate hash and your hash.

Comment: In my link to firebase it is in capital letters as NumberMania but originally it is in small letters numbermania

Comment: cerificate hash it's a var name and your hash is your SHA1 key

Comment: please edit my json file.i could not understand your answer

Comment: *"oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "791746437202-4t8b5449cj270cas8e8u2klsjbv9mj3m.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3,
"android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.example.personal.numbermania",
            "certificate_hash": "your_SHA1"
          }
        }
      ],*

Comment: Now add your SHA-1 key and rebuild project! :)

Comment: what is SHA-1 key and where should i add it?

Comment: what is certificate_hash ?

Comment: Sorry but the gms error (or library error) at start, it's solved, this error is other thing and I can't helps you because I never implement ad's in Android... :(

Comment: To obtain sha1 follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool

Comment: Oh man you saved my day. in my case that was because i didn't add google play service in my sdk manager.

Answer (score 23):

Had the same problem.

adding this to my dependency didn't solve

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Adding this solved for me

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'

to the root build.gradle.

Comment: Ooops, I used the app `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 14):

simply add "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'" to android/build.gradle to look like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}
```

and also add  "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"  to  the end of file in android/app/build.gradle to look like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 12):

Go To `Setting > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Google Play Services`

[image]

Comment: This worked for me and was such a simple fix.

Answer (score 10):

On upgrading to Android Studio 4.2.1, I was prompted to set dependency:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.7'
```

However, this caused "Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found".
Leaving it as follows fixed the problem:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
```

EDIT:

This problem has now been fixed in:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
```

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' 
worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about you, but I spent about 30 minutes troubleshooting the same issue here, until I realized that the line for app/build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and not:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'
```

Eg: I had copied that line from a tutorial, but when specifying the apply plugin namespace, no colon (`:`) is required. It's, in fact, a dot. (`.`).

Hey... it's easy to miss.

Comment: Man, you saved my day . This was exactly the issue

Answer (score 7):

The Google docs during the Android setup process didn't quite work for me. It seems like Google need to update their docs. The only solution that worked for me was:

1. As part of enabling Google APIs or Firebase services in your Android application you may have to add the google-services plugin to your project level `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    // ...
}
```

This plugin will allow to process the `google-services.json` file and produce Android resources that can be used in your application's code. Also, it will allow to install dependencies for Firebase related libraries, which is going to be the next step.

2. Add this line to the app level `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Sources:

- https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Answer (score 5):

In build.gradle(Module:app) add this code

```
dependencies {
    ……..
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1’
    ……  
}
```

If you still have a problem after that, then add this code in build.gradle(Module:app)

```
defaultConfig {
    ….
    …...
    multiDexEnabled true
}


dependencies {
    …..
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Result - Adding multiDexEnabled true & compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' does not solve the issue.  Can you explain how this is supposed to fix the issue?

Answer (score 4):

In the app `build.gradle` dependency, you must add the following code

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:$last_version'
```

And then please check the Google Play Service SDK tools installing status.

Answer (score 4):

Ended up on this thread while trying to integrate Firebase with a Flutter application. So, in case you are facing the same problem in Flutter, below steps solved the issue for me.

> **Disclaimer**: first steps are the same as described in the documentation
> and every answer/tutorial found online. I am just mentioning them on a
> high level for the sake of keeping my answer **consistent**.
>
> *The actual step* that is different and solved the issue is the **last
> one**.

1. Add google-services.json in your flutter_app/android/app directory.
2. On android/build.gradle add:

> ```
> repositories {
>     google()
>     jcenter()
>     maven {
>         url "https://maven.google.com"
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
>         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
>         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
>     }
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>         maven {
>             url "https://maven.google.com"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. On android/app/build.gradle add:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
> apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> ```

4. On android/app/build.gradle add also the following:

> ```
> dependencies {
>     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
>
>     implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
>
>     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
>     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
>     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
> }
> ```

You can find a working demo for this here https://gitlab.com/ecocupaegean/ecocupaegean/-/tree/master/, in order to run the app you just need to add your own google-services.json, and specify an API KEY for google maps geolocation API.

Answer (score 3):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

add above line at the bottom of your app gradle.build.

Comment: @subrahmanyam-boyapati Why at the bottom? what's the deal? I think is more important to explain why

Comment: I doubt that position determines the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I changed google-services classpath version from 4.2.0 to 3.0.0

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Then rebuild the project, Then strangely it suggested me to add firebase core to the project.

Then I added firebase core on the app(module)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.8'
```

Then the error disappeared magically.

Answer (score 2):

Non of the answers above helped in my case, but following this tutorial thoroughly did.
[Maps SDK for Android / Set up an Android Studio project](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config)

Answer (score 1):

In project's build.gradle add the following

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially had `classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'` and it was not working. It worked when I changed to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using build-gradle.kt

add this

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        // Android Build Server
        maven { url = uri("../nowinandroid-prebuilts/m2repository") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple solution:
Go to build.gradle(project) and in dependencies add following class path:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
```

Now make sure to add updated service if available >4.4.0
Build again. Done

Answer (score 1):

```
id("com.google.gms.google-services")
```

use this insitead of

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-servies'
```

this is applicable and used for latest versions of android studio

Answer (score 1):

If you using `kts` then specify the version in `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "put_version_here"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android bumblebee Just add this code on top in the build.gradle <Project .> file

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
```

Now try to add plugin in build.gradle <app .> like this

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```