# Unable to merge dex - android studio 3.0 update

Tags: android, android-studio, merge, build.gradle, dex

Tried almost every suggestion on the internet :( I've cleaned and rebuild my project dozens of times, messed with multiDexEnabled plenty of times and so on.  If anyone can help that would be fantastic.  Just updated android studio to 3.0 and can't run my app for nothing.  Thank you in advance!

Getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project_bc.project_bc"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //fireBase
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'me.kaelaela:verticalviewpager:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    compile 'eu.davidea:flipview:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.wajahatkarim3.EasyFlipView:EasyFlipView:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle Console stacktrace:

```
    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/amenparham/AndroidStudioProjects/Project_BC/app/google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface;\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface;

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface;
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface;
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:230)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

21 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 19 up-to-date
```

Comment: Yesterday I was also getting exception during dex merge.  It turned out to be because of duplicate class in two jar files.. (same package same class name). Is it same case for you?  Please check the exception detail/log.

Comment: Where do i find those at :)  Still kind of new to android studio

Comment: Inside Gradle console? Messages?  I am also kinda new to AS :-).  In my case I was running a console build for a library..

Comment: Would it help to show you my Gradle Console Messages?

Comment: Not sure.. No harm if you edit and post above I guess..

Comment: There you go at bottom :) I am reading through it as well.

Comment: Not much to go there.. It says try to run with stacktrace, info, debug etc., but I don't know how to go about.. Try clean and build again.. Sometimes disabling Instant Run helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some problem is with Your versions.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
...
Maybe order in this is problem.
Try this. I hope it will work.

Comment: After adding that i get new error saying: Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface;

Comment: added it above under: Gradle Console stacktrace

Comment: getting caused by ending with OpenCameraInterface

Comment: Maybe try restart computer or try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42176016/7092449

Comment: went to that link and added those dependencies and it worked!!! Your a life saver pal