# Add gradle plugin to Cordova app (Android)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I am trying to integrate a gradle plugin (specific, Firebase Distribution but it can be any other) in my Cordova app (only for the Android side) but it keep gives me error that the plugin not found.

I am using the build-extras.gradle file as explained in the documentation like this:

```
 //build-extras.gradle
 buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:3.1.1'
   }
}

ext.postBuildExtras = {
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
}
```

When sync gradle i am getting the following error:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution' not found.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with v 3.1.1 instead?

Comment: @Eric Yes, it didn't helped, please refer to edited question. This happens for any plugin not just firebase.

Comment: Looks like you could be missing play services ? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892622/plugin-with-id-com-google-gms-google-services-not-found

Comment: @Eric, Thanks, but it didn't helped, updated the code in question accordingly