# Getting this error (see screenshot) while trying to sync after adding the required lines needed to use google firebase. How to solve this?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

Was expecting for it to sync properly. (Also, the build.gradle (project) i.e. top level build file seem very different than what its supposed to look like according to firebase and does not have dependencies, so I put the line supposed to be in it under its dependencies too in the other build gradle file (which is in the screenshot) and even if I write it in the top level build file after incorporating "dependencies{ }" there, still the error remains. I am using Android studio Electric Eel bdw). And I don't have enough knowledge about gradle files and how they work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892622/plugin-with-id-com-google-gms-google-services-not-found)

Comment: I had already added the required json file to app directory.